# How to delete events on iPad Calendar.app

Tags: ipad, calendar

I have been able to add events on my iPad calendar but I don't see how I can delete an event.

Comment: Nothing popped up when I tapped on the event. This used to work on previous version of iPad OS but not with OS 14.3 I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch Calendar.
2. Tap on the event you would like to delete.
3. Tap on `Edit` in the upper right hand corner.
4. Tap on `Delete Event` at the bottom.
5. Tap on `Delete Event` once again once it pops up to confirm that you
   want to delete that event.